# @StringRes, @DrawableRes, @LayoutRes and so on android annotations lint check with kotlin parameters

Tags: android, kotlin

assuming you have such data class with default parameters

```
data class Info(
        @DrawableRes
        val iconRes: Int = 0,
        @StringRes
        val stringRes: Int = 0,
        @LayoutRes
        val layoutRes: Int = 0)
```

so you can create this data-class like

```
    val data = Info(
        iconRes = R.drawable.icon, 
        stringRes = R.string.text,
        layoutRes = R.layout.layout)
```

in this case there isn't any lint error

But when i try to use default parameters a lint error is occured:

```
val data = Info(
        //here is expected resource of type drawable error
        stringRes = R.string.text
        layoutRes = R.layout.layout)
```

Seems that it uses position in parameters, not the exact type & name.

I've tried to use explicit annotation like `@param:DrawableRes`, but with the same result.

Can i somehow solve this problem? I use latest Android Studio 3.0.

Comment: It's not just you, this issue has been present for months now. I have a library that I'd like to update with these annotations but they don't seem to produce lint errors when you're calling the methods from Kotlin code.

Comment: 2018 with Android stuido 3.3 beta 4 and they still don't work, for enum parameters at least. It does work for normal functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was an issue in Android Studio and was fixed in 3.1. Checked on 3.1-beta4