# Set a constraint on a function parameter in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to set a constraint on a parameter in a function in kotlin.

I've tried using,

```
fun test(@IntRange(from = 0, to = 1) size: Int){
   ...
}
```

which works fine in java, but it doesn't seem to have any effect in kotlin.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/47016590/4465208 . The answer for now is that checking of these sort of Android support annotations is spotty at best when using them from Kotlin, although slowly improving. I'm tracking the issue in relation to the various resource annotations on one of my libraries [here](https://github.com/zsmb13/MaterialDrawerKt/issues/55).

Comment: That's a bummer, thanks!

Comment: It was a bug in Android Studio fixed in 3.1

Comment: Still not fixed for all cases, see: https://github.com/zsmb13/MaterialDrawerKt/issues/55#issuecomment-363488824

Comment: I only use it in functions (at least for now) so I missed that, good to know.